# How to browse Excel file and import using a button

Tags: c#, linq, import

I have two buttons(LoadFile and ImportFile). I want to click load file and browser for Excel file from the directy and then click Import button so that it will load the data into the table in the database. Excel Sheet is called "BankStatement" with more than 1000 rows. I haven't done it before, I am doing this using Linq to SQL .

This is my coding but am not sure how to proceed or get the a way. Can someone please help me. Thanks

Loading

```
    public void LoadExcel()
    {
        string _LoadPath = @"C:\NewFNBFile1.xls";
        TextBox1.Text = _LoadPath.ToString();

        var _File = new ExcelQueryFactory(_LoadPath);

        _File.AddMapping("Number", "Number");
        _File.AddMapping("DateReceived", "DateReceived");
        _File.AddMapping("Description1", "Description1"
        _File.AddMapping("Description2", "Description2");
        _File.AddMapping("Description3", "Description3");
        _File.AddMapping("Amount", "Amount");
        _File.AddMapping("Balance", "Balance");
        _File.AddMapping("AccruedCharges", "AccruedCharges");

    }

    protected void btnBroswer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadExcel();
    }
```

Import

```
    protected void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        var _list = new ExcelQueryFactory(@"C:\NewFNBFile1.xls");
        var _Show = from x in _dc.TESTING_NewBankFile1_s
                    where x ["Description3"] == "A19C28425645285"
                        select new
                        {
                            Number = x["Number"],
                            DateReceived = x["DateReceived"],
                            Description1 = x["Description1"],
                            Description2 = x["Description2"],
                            Description3 = x["Description3"],
                            Amount = x["Amount"],
                            Balance = x["Balance"],
                            AccruedCharges = x["AccruedCharges"],                               
                        }; 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

please refer the below c# code

```
public System.Data.DataTable GetTable(string filename, string SheetName, string outTableName)
{
    OleDbConnection oleConn = null;
    OleDbDataAdapter oleAdapter = null;
    try
    {
        string Con = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                     @"Data Source=" + filename + ";" +
                     @"Extended Properties=" + Convert.ToChar(34).ToString() +
                     @"Excel 12.0;" + "Imex=1;" + "HDR=Yes;" + Convert.ToChar(34).ToString() ;

        oleConn = new OleDbConnection(Con);
        oleConn.Open();
        OleDbCommand oleCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand();
        oleCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand(
                @"SELECT * FROM ["
                + SheetName
                + "$" + "]", oleConn);
        oleAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        oleAdapter.SelectCommand = oleCmdSelect;
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable(outTableName);
        oleAdapter.FillSchema(dt, SchemaType.Source);
        oleAdapter.Fill(dt);
        oleCmdSelect.Dispose();
        oleCmdSelect = null;
        oleAdapter.Dispose();
        oleAdapter = null;
        oleConn.Dispose();
        oleConn = null;              
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, After copying this method, which code to put under the import button?

Comment: Just call the method

 GetTable("Test.xls", "Sheet1", "DTResult")